# Prestashop 1.5.6 Add New Product Page

Tags: prestashop

I am a developer but new to Prestashop (not really familiar with template because i am not a web developer but getting there..) but just helping my friend manage his website.

I checked the current version is 1.5.6 and am trying to add a new fieled in **Product** table and add another description input area in the following page.

[image]

I had a look at **Product.php** (classes > product.php), **AdminProductsController.php** (controllers > admin > adminproductscontroller.php) and **Products.tpl** (themes > uhu023v15 > products.tpl) but none of them seemed relevant to me. Not sure which files I need to modify. Please help.

Comment: I think you would be better off on the Prestashop documentation site or their fora. This is not exactly a real programming question, unless you have problems with specific code in the templates itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need go to

> adminXXXX/themes/default/template/controllers/products/informations.tpl

because this is backend template (product.tpl is frontend template and what customer see when view product)

there You will find

```
            <tr>
                <td class="col-left">
                    {include file="controllers/products/multishop/checkbox.tpl" field="description_short" type="tinymce" multilang="true"}
                    <label>{l s='Short description:'}<br /></label>
                    <p class="product_description">({l s='Appears in the product list(s), and on the top of the product page.'})</p>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                        {include file="controllers/products/textarea_lang.tpl"
                        languages=$languages
                        input_name='description_short'
                        input_value=$product->description_short
                        max=$PS_PRODUCT_SHORT_DESC_LIMIT}
                    <p class="clear"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     **Your HERE** ;)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-left">
                    {include file="controllers/products/multishop/checkbox.tpl" field="description" type="tinymce" multilang="true"}
                    <label>{l s='Description:'}<br /></label>
                    <p class="product_description">({l s='Appears in the body of the product page'})</p>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                        {include file="controllers/products/textarea_lang.tpl" languages=$languages
                        input_name='description'
                        input_value=$product->description
                        }
                    <p class="clear"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

From there You need to duplicate whole textarea block and find and duplicate according functions (not sure where)